# oledbexception 'unspecified error' when filling dataset

Tags: vb.net

So, i get the OleDBException "unspecified error" whenever the function below hits the dataAdapter.Fill(dataset) line.

I have tried adding dbcommand.connection.close() and dbcommand.connection.dispose() but neither fixed the problem.

I assume that this error would happen every time i try to connect with the DB but this is just the first function that does so in my code, so this is where the error is first occuring.

I have read online that MySQL will eventually clear out old connections after a while, if this is true, then i should just have to wait..but i dont want to keep waiting for nothing to happen.

```
    Function GetOrders(ByVal _numberrecords As Long) As DataTable
Dim TaxConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(TaxConnStr)
Try
    'Code to get orders in call status. Sort oldest to newest
    ' dbConnection.Open()
    Dim queryString As String
    queryString = "SELECT TOP " & _numberrecords & " Orders.Control_Number, Orders.State, Orders.County, Orders.Status, Orders.ZipCode, Orders.OrderNumber, Orders.Client, Orders.Department "
    queryString += "FROM Orders "
    queryString += "WHERE(((Orders.Status) = 'Tax Cert Call' Or (Orders.Status) = 'Online')) "
    queryString += "ORDER BY Orders.Date_Received;"
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
    dbCommand.CommandText = queryString
    dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
    'dbCommand.Connection.Close()
    'dbCommand.Connection.Dispose()
    'dbCommand.Dispose()
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
    If dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        GetOrders = dataSet.Tables(0)
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    myLogger.Log(ex.Message)
Finally
    dbConnection.Close()

    dbConnection.Dispose()
End Try
```

End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My Access Database was corrupted. I just remade the database and it all worked like gravy.